# How to handle different date types in the same column with Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working with a CSV file that have one column for dates,
however for some reason the list contains different date types.
one type is 24-06-2022 00:00:00, and the other type is 24/6/2022 0:00

When i import the list, the data type in the column is objects, and then i change the datatype to datetime object

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],errors ='coerce')
```

The problem is that then the information is wrong, it is like its reading the month incorrectly for some of the data.

How can i change so that i have the same data type for all entries?

Comment: Which pandas version do you have? this should work fine. edit: it **does** work fine, gives me `2022-06-24` in both cases

Comment: my offer is first use apply method and change type on which is different  or use format object in to_datetime

Comment: As said here before. the best way to to convert everything into a canonic representation by using the apply method before doing the needed actions. You can either convert the dates to the datetime object or convert the dates strings.